# Using Gio.SimpleAction argument in stateless action

Tags: gtk3, gio

The documentation for Gio.SimpleAction.new says that I can specify a name, which is a string, and a parameter type, which is a GLib.VariantType (or None). If I specify a GLib.VariantType for the second argument, how do I specify its value?

I know that I can specify an argument in the connect call for the action, but then the first argument in the handler gets None. It seems as if it could be useful to specify a value for that argument, but I am not seeing how that is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify it's value in [g_action_activate](https://developer.gnome.org/gio//2.54/GAction.html#g-action-activate).

Thus, you do the following, e.g. for boolean:

```
vtype = GLib.VariantType.new("b")
action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("name", vtype)
# action.connect ("activate", handler, *args)
value = GLib.Variant.new_boolean (True)
a.activate(value)
```

Comment: Thanks. So, if the action is activated automatically (e.g., by a mouse click on a menu item) then there is no way to specify an argument?

Comment: @beezergeezer like `user_data` in signal connection? Looks like no.